# How can I get a low power virtual machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, power-consumption

How can I get a low power Linux virtual machine?

I usually use virtual machines on my laptop to use some GNU/Linux programs, and I've found that at the very moment I start a Virtual Box machine, the Windows timer resolution goes from ~15ms to ~1ms, increasing the power consumption about 1-3W:

```
Maximum timer interval: 15.625 ms
Minimum timer interval: 0.500 ms
Current timer interval: 0.978 ms
```

Is there any way to prevent this? Maybe using a specific kernel or a diferent virtualization software?

Comment: Have you tried Hyper-V?

Comment: @grawity I'm using Windows 8 (not 8.1), I've searched and It looks that Hyper-V works with Windows Server.